# How to convert two characters into a string?

Tags: c, string, char, integer, atoi

I've the following string saved into a char array named `buffer`:

```
{app_id:9401}
```

I want to obtain two integers: 94 and 01. I want to convert `buffer[8]` and `buffer[9]` into the first integer(`94`) and `buffer[10]` and `buffer[11]` into the second integer (`1`). I'm trying to do it, but I obtain segmentation fault. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char buffer[] = "{app_id:9401}";

    printf("First number:%c%c. Second Number: %c%c\n", buffer[8], buffer[9], buffer[10], buffer[11]);

    char first_number[10] = "";
    strcat(first_number, buffer[8]);
    strcat(first_number, buffer[9]);

    int x = atoi(first_number);
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

Comment: C specifies that all digit characters should be consecutively encoded, which means you can subtract `'0'` from any digit character to get its integer equivalent (i.e. `'9' - '0' == 9`). Then iit's just a matter of decimal arithmetic to putt all the four digits together.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally include a [mre], which includes a function `main` and all necessary `#include` directives. If you hard-code the input, for example with `char buffer[] = "{app_id:9401}";`, and then apply the posted code into a function `main`, are you able to reproduce the error? If yes, then please post this as a [mre].

Comment: Since you did not respond to my request for a [mre], I have now converted your posted code to one myself. Feel free to [edit] your question if you are not happy with my changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way, by example. Scan two integers from the string, each with a maximum length of 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[] = "{app_id:9401}";
    int x, y;
    if(sscanf(buffer + 8, "%2d%2d", &x, &y) == 2)
        printf ("x=%d y=%d\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x=94 y=1
```

If you don't know where the number is in the string, you can find the colon with

```
char *cptr = strchr(buffer, ':');
```

Comment: Although this answer provides a good solution to OP's problem, it does not answer OP's question why OP's code is causing a segmentation fault. (I am still upvoting the answer, though.)

Answer (score 0):

> [...] but I obtain segmentation fault. Why?

The function `strcat` requires both function arguments to be pointers to strings. However, you are not providing a pointer as a function argument. Instead, you are passing the value of a single character. Any good compiler should warn you about this, provided that you have warnings enabled. I suggest that you ensure that you always do have them enabled. See this question for further information:

[Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings)

This invalid function argument is probably the reason for your segmentation fault.

Using the function `strcat` is probably not what you want, because you want to concatenate a single character to a string, instead of a string to a string. The C standard library does not provide a function which does this. However, you can easily implement such a function yourself:

```
void concatentate_string_with_character( char *dest, char c )
{
    //calculate length of destination string
    size_t length = strlen( dest );

    //overwrite terminating null character with new character
    dest[length] = c;

    //write new terminating null character
    dest[length+1] = '\0';
}
```

If you replace in your code the function `strcat` with `concatentate_string_with_character`, then it will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void concatentate_string_with_character( char *dest, char c )
{
    //calculate length of destination string
    size_t length = strlen( dest );

    //overwrite terminating null character with new character
    dest[length] = c;

    //write new terminating null character
    dest[length+1] = '\0';
}

int main( void )
{
    char buffer[] = "{app_id:9401}";

    char first_number[10] = "";
    concatentate_string_with_character( first_number, buffer[8] );
    concatentate_string_with_character( first_number, buffer[9] );
    int x = atoi( first_number );
    printf( "%d\n", x );
}
```

This program has the correct output `94`.

However, instead of using a separate function for this, it would probably be easier to simply define the three elements of `first_number` yourself:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    char buffer[] = "{app_id:9401}";

    char first_number[] = { buffer[8], buffer[9], '\0' };

    int x = atoi( first_number );
    printf( "%d\n", x );
}
```

This program also has the correct output `94`.